# WebClient proxy not working

Tags: c#, proxy, webclient

I created this method to test whether the given proxy data is valid:

```
public static async Task<bool> TestConnection(string ip, int port)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add("UserAgent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
                var proxy = new WebProxy(ip, port) {UseDefaultCredentials = true};

                client.Proxy = proxy;
                client.OpenRead(new Uri("http://google.com"));
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Trace(ex, "Failed to connect to proxy {0}:{1}", ip, port);
        }

        return false;
    });
}
```

I tested it several times with different proxy servers listed on some websites. The result is always this exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
```

Why is this happening? These proxies do not require a authentication.

Comment: simply don't use `UseDefaultCredentials` BTW: Correct header for UserAgent is `User-Agent`

Comment: Removed it and it ended in giving me a 504 gateway timeout

Comment: You may want to post a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this link may also help http://sscce.org/

Comment: What's missing in your opinion @L.B

Comment: Your proxy doesn't work? You use wrong ip/port for proxy? Your proxy doesn't support https? Who knows...